# question about RSA encryption

Tags: cryptography

A number $x$ has been encrypted with the RSA encryption to

$x^5 = 16 \mod 35$

What is $x$?

I know that the answer must be 11, but has anyone an idea how to find out x in a systematic way? I could not find such a way to solve it (with public key and privat key). I think there must be another possibility. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The public modulus is small enough so that you know the value of $\varphi (35) = 24$.  Since the public encryption key is $e=5$ you can find the private decryption key by computing $d = 5^{-1} \mod 24$ (by pure coincidence, this is 5 again).  Get out a modular calculator and do this.  Now decrypt the message by $16^d \mod 35$.  Done.

Answer (score 2):

The point of the RSA system is that there *isn't* a good method, unless we have a way to factor the modulus.

However, modern computers are powerful enough to be able to factor two-digit numbers in a reasonable time -- in fact you can [look up the factors of 35](http://factordb.com/index.php?query=35) on the internet and find $35=5\cdot 7$ and therefore $\varphi(35)=(5-1)(7-1)=24$.

This is important because we then know that $x^{24n+1}\equiv x \pmod{35}$ for every $n$ and a7ll $x$. So if you find a $k$ such that $5k\equiv 1\pmod{24}$ you have $x\equiv x^{5k} \equiv (x^5)^k \pmod{35}$ so raising $16$ to the $k$th power will give you $x$.

Solving $5k\equiv 1\pmod{24}$ is *modular division*, which you can do using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).